# Conditionally loading an external spring boot autoconfiguration based on loaded profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following requirements while loading an autoconfiguration (via `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `spring.factories`:

- Exclude the autoconfiguration based on the current profile
- Don't modify the imported autoconfigurations (starter jars)

The only options I can think off are:

- adding a flag property in the autoconfiguration
- adding a `@Profile` annotation on the autoconfiguration

But both options require modifying the autoconfiguration starter jars, which I prefer not to.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it is All about @ComponentScan, you will need to make 2 parent auto-configuration for 2 profiles, one with @ComponentScan with package including your others children auto-configurations, and another one to exclude the auto-configuration you don't want in this profile, if you want to scan the package including this auto-configuration except this auto-configuration, you can use [excludeFilters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--)

Comment: Do you mean I have to create my own configuration for my imported autoconfiguration jar to facilitate exclusions for profiles?

Comment: you have your own SpringBootApplication class which include component scan annotations correct ? this component scan can have excludeFilters and includeFilters, you will need to have 2 parent AutoConfiguration one with component scan that include configuration you want and another one to exclude it

Comment: Yes, I have my own Spring Boot Application, but the jars are configured automatically (similar to starters) via ``@EnableAutoConfiguration``

Comment: Ok, to include your other Auto configurations you have @ComponentScan with the package name correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand correctly. But no, I'm receiving all my beans via automatic wiring of configurations by spring boot (classpath scanning). No ``@ComponentScan`` was used, only ``@EnableAutoConfiguration``.

Comment: Please see the following link for reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html